# how to access namespaces in kubernetes using rest api?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

I am unable to get list of namespaces using rest api and rest end point is `https://<localhost>:8001/api/v1/namespaces`

Using [this kubernetes document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#list-namespace-v1-core):

I am using postman. I will repeat the steps:

1. Created a user and given cluster admin privileges:

`kubectl create serviceaccount exampleuser`

2. Created a rolebinding for our user with cluster role cluster-admin:

`kubectl create rolebinding <nameofrolebinding> --clusterrole cluster-admin 
      --serviceaccount default:exampleuser`

3. Checked rolebinding using:

`kubectl describe rolebinding <nameofrolebinding>`

4. Now by using:

`kubectl describe serviceaccount exampleuser
 kubectl describe secret exampleuser-xxxx-xxxx`

I will use token I got here to authenticate postman.

```
GET https://<ipofserver>:port/api/v1/namespace
```

AUTH using bearer token.

Expected result to list all namespaces in cluster. like
`kubectl get namespaces`. But got a warning as follows.

```
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "namespaces is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:exampleuser\" cannot list resource \"namespaces\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope",
    "reason": "Forbidden",
    "details": {
        "kind": "namespaces"
    },
    "code": 403
}
```

I have used "cluster-admin" clusterrole for the user, still getting authentication related error.
please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `clusterrolebinding` instead of `rolebinding`:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding <nameofrolebinding> --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount default:exampleuser
```

`RoleBinding` means permissions to a namespaced resources, but `namespace` is not a `namespaced` resources, you can check this by `kubectl api-resouces`.

More detail at [rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding):

> Permissions can be granted within a namespace with a RoleBinding, or cluster-wide with a ClusterRoleBinding

Answer (score 0):

so issue is instead of using **rolebinding** , i need to use **clusterrolebinding** check below

`kubectl create rolebinding nameofrolebinding --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount default:exampleuser`

`kubectl create clusterrolebinding nameofrolebinding --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount default:exampleuser`

**rolebinding** scope is upto a **namespace** and
**clusterrolebinding** scope is entire **cluster**.

To work with api/v1/namespaces we need to use **clusterrolebinding**